# Truncation operator

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm currently working on this question, and I'm unsure how to determine if it is time-invariant or not. When I perform y(t-t0), does it shift even the time at which the step is defined? Furthermore, when I shift the input, does the step output remain defined only for t <= α
[image]

Comment: Plot the result for some simple cases over time and consider the meaning of time invariant.  Consider also what u(t) or ranges of t would have to be in order to make the system meet each of the classifications it mentions.